# C# Replace the end of a string starting from the position of a match

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string (from a filename) like this: `Mytext_edit1345.jpg`

I just want to cut the "_edit1345" so I can get `Mytext.jpg` as a result.

Is `Regex.Replace` the best way to go for me?

`string result =  Regex.Replace(Bildname, pattern, "");`

What pattern do i need?

Comment: don't use a regex for this....It's overkill.

Comment: We don't know what pattern you need, or even if you need to use `Replace`, because you have not specified the rules. A single example != rules. What happens if the name has multiple underscores? What if it has no underscores? What... if...

Comment: Please don't just ask us to do it for you. While there's an unfortunate number of people willing to spoon-feed solutions to questions like this, it's still discouraged.

Comment: If you are keen on using a RegEx, have a play with http://regexpal.com to work out what you need. But, (without knowing the rules on the spec on the format of filenames) I would say that at first-glance a RegEx does seem like overkill as per @MitchWheat comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below pattern to match the substring(from`_`  upto the next `.`) you want to cut-down,

```
_[^.]*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hO5rO8/6)

Your code would be,

```
string str = "Mytext_edit1345.jpg";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"_[^.]*", "");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/wh6u7f)

Comment: I think someone is downvoting the correct answers! +1 to nullify that!

Answer (score 2):

Use `String.Substring` with `Path.GetExtension` like:

```
string fileName = "Mytext_edit1345.jpg";
string newFileName = fileName;
if (fileName.Contains('_'))
{
    newFileName = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.IndexOf('_')) +
                 Path.GetExtension(fileName);
}
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I think it is better to use some inbuilt functions than using Regex!

Comment: @TimSchmelter, not really sure, but the sample file name has an underscore, if the fileName doesn't contains an underscore, that can be checked `if(fileName.Contains('_'))`

Comment: @TimSchmelter OP should be more general then... but whatever.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I have modified the code to modify file name only if `_` is present.

Comment: Thanks for your help from all of you, next time i will make a more precise description of my problem...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Path` class and string methods like `String.Remove`

```
string fileNameWOE = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
int indexOfUnderscore = fileNameWOE.IndexOf('_');
if(indexOfUnderscore >= 0)
    fileNameWOE = fileNameWOE.Remove(indexOfUnderscore);
fileName = fileNameWOE + Path.GetExtension(fileName);
```